# WP Gutenberg - custom block with two content fields

Tags: javascript, block-editor

I'm developing Gutenberg custom block for accodrdions on my website. My code was working with only one content field. When I have added second props it has stop worked and console says:

> Cannot read property 'content' of undefined

```
wp.blocks.registerBlockType('myblock/question-block', {
  title: 'Blok Pytan',
  icon: 'dashicons-welcome-write-blog',
  category: 'common',
  attributes: {
    header: {type: 'string'},
      content: {type: 'string'}
  },
  edit: function(props, propstwo) {

      function updateheader(event) {
      props.setAttributes({header: event.target.value})
    }

       function updatecontent(event) {
      propstwo.setAttributes({content: event.target.value})
    }

    return wp.element.createElement(
      "div",
      null,
      wp.element.createElement(
        "h2",
        null,
        "Nagłówek tekstu"
      ),
      wp.element.createElement("input", { type: "text", value: props.attributes.header, onChange: updateheader }),
    ),
         wp.element.createElement(
        "p",
        null,
        "Rozwijany tekst"
      ),
        wp.element.createElement("input", { type: "text", value: propstwo.attributes.content, onChange: updatecontent })

  },
  save: function(props, propstwo) {

    return wp.element.createElement(
    "div",
    {className: "accodrion"},

    wp.element.createElement(
      "h2",
      {className: "accodrdion-header"},
      props.attributes.header
    ),

    wp.element.createElement(
      "p",
      {className: "panel"},
      propstwo.attributes.content
    )   

  )}
})
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You don't need `propstwo`. It doesn't serve any purpose. There's only one `props` argument, and you use it to get access to your block's `attributes`. Both `header` and `content` are attributes, so you access both of them through the same `props` argument:

```
wp.blocks.registerBlockType('myblock/question-block', {
    title: 'Blok Pytan',
    icon: 'dashicons-welcome-write-blog',
    category: 'common',
    attributes: {
        header: {
            type: 'string'
        },
        content: {
            type: 'string'
        }
    },
    edit: function(props) {
        function updateheader(event) {
            props.setAttributes({
                header: event.target.value
            })
        }
        function updatecontent(event) {
            props.setAttributes({
                content: event.target.value
            })
        }
        return wp.element.createElement(
            "div",
            null,
            wp.element.createElement(
                "h2",
                null,
                "Nagłówek tekstu"
            ),
            wp.element.createElement(
                "input",
                {
                    type: "text",
                    value: props.attributes.header,
                    onChange: updateheader
                }
            ),
            wp.element.createElement(
                "p",
                null,
                "Rozwijany tekst"
            ),
            wp.element.createElement(
                "input",
                {
                    type: "text",
                    value: props.attributes.content,
                    onChange: updatecontent
                }
            ),
        );
    },
    save: function(props) {
        return wp.element.createElement(
            "div",
            {
                className: "accodrion",
            },
            wp.element.createElement(
                "h2", {
                    className: "accodrdion-header"
                },
                props.attributes.header
            ),
            wp.element.createElement(
                "p", {
                    className: "panel"
                },
                props.attributes.content
            )
        );
    }
})
```

You also hadn't correctly nested the child elements in your `edit` function, which I've also corrected above.

Answer (score 0):

@jacob

The last comma on the ) before save needs to be removed, otherwise it's golden:

```
),<--here
```

},
save: function(props) {